# What caused this warning in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-routing

> browser.js: Warning: [react-router] the `History` mixin is
>   deprecated, please access `context.router` with your own
>   `contextTypes`.

My routes file

```
const routes = (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={RootComponent}>
          <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />

          <Route path="profile" component={ProfilePage} >
            <IndexRoute component={ProfilePage} />
            <Route path="view/:profileId" component={ProfilePage} />
            <Route path="add" component={AddProfile} />
            <Route path="edit/:profileId" component={EditProfile} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="onboard" component={Onboard} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
  </Provider>
);

export default routes;
```

And root

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import routes from './routes';
import "babel-polyfill";

const mountPoint = document.getElementById('application-root');

if (mountPoint) {
  render(routes, mountPoint);
} else {
  console.error('could not find application mount point');
}
```

React-router v2.6.1

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that emits that warning and check the stack trace up to the place where this thing is checked. Then you know what exactly causes it.

Answer (score 1):

The error might be caused by this line. Where are you importing 'browserHistory' from?

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
```

In the latest version of react-router, you need to import history from react-router package itself

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
```

Refer [this link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) for further details